# project wsgi not found when started automatically but not manually

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord

I do not understand why I get an error about not finding my "project.wsgi" module when supervisor tries to start the app automatically (for example when the server is starting.)

```
2014-02-15 05:13:05 [1011] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-02-15 05:13:05 [1016] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1016
2014-02-15 05:13:05 [1016] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/local/sites/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/var/local/sites/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/var/local/sites/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/var/local/sites/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/var/local/sites/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/var/local/sites/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named myproject.wsgi
```

Whereas I do not get this error and it works fine when I manually do:

```
sudo supervisorctl start myapp
```

What is different?

Thanks

### UPDATE:

supervisor conf file:

```
[program:myproject]
command=/var/local/sites/myproject/run/gunicorn_start                       ; Command to start app
user=myproject                                             ; User to run as
autostart=true
autorestart=true
loglevel=info
redirect_stderr=false
stdout_logfile=/var/local/sites/myproject/logs/supervisor-myproject-stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile=/var/local/sites/myproject/logs/supervisor-myproject-stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB
```

/var/local/sites/myproject/run/gunicorn_start:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="myproject_app"         # Name of the application
USER=myproject          # the user to run as
GROUP=myproject        # the group to run as

NUM_WORKERS=3                       # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn

# Logs config
LOG_LEVEL=info
ACCESS_LOGFILE=/var/local/sites/myproject/logs/gunicorn-myproject-access.log
ERROR_LOGFILE=/var/local/sites/myproject/logs/gunicorn-myproject-error.log

echo "Starting $NAME"        

exec envdir /var/local/sites/myproject/env_vars /var/local/sites/myproject/venv/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --bind=unix:/tmp/myproject.gunicorn.sock \
  --access-logfile=$ACCESS_LOGFILE \
  --error-logfile=$ERROR_LOGFILE
```

Comment: Show your `site.conf` config of supervisor

Comment: I added it to my post. Thanks.

Comment: I also added my gunicorn start script that supervisor uses. Do you think it could be related to the fact that I use envdir? But I still do not understand why it works when I run the script manually then... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add `directory` to your supervisor configuration file. This is my template. I use this in every project and works fine:

```
[program:PROJECT_NAME]
command=/opt/sites/PROJECT_NAME/env/bin/gunicorn -c /opt/sites/etc/gunicorn/GUNICORN_CONF.conf.py PROJECT_NAME.wsgi:application
directory=/opt/sites/PROJECT_NAME
environment=PATH="/opt/sites/PROJECT/env/bin"
autostart=true
autorestart=false
redirect_stderr=True
stdout_logfile=/tmp/PROJECT_NAME.stdout
```

Comment: I tried it => did not change it. When the server starts, the app fails to start automatically. Could it have something to do with running it with sudo when I do it manually?

Comment: you cant test if the user you're using works by using `sudo su - username` and then running the gunicorn_start file

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before. I'm using the following line in my gunicorn_start instead of `envdir`. I'm running a django application within a virtual env located in `/env/nafd/` and my django app is located in `/env/nafd/nafd_proj`

```
..
DJANGODIR=/to/path/app_proj
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate`

exec ../bin/gunicorn nafd_proj.wsgi:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --bind=unix:/tmp/myproject.gunicorn.sock \
  --access-logfile=$ACCESS_LOGFILE \
  --error-logfile=$ERROR_LOGFILE`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious, but it is worth to mention:

> check if "supervisord" daemon is running (service supervisor status).

Here is the following setup that I have here, using a Flask app with WSGI (Gunicorn), controlled via Supervisor, and it is working perfectly.

**Flask App**

```
root@ilg40:~# ll /etc/tdm/flask/
total 1120
drwx------ 5 root root   4096 Jan 24 19:47 ./
drwx------ 3 root root   4096 Jan 23 00:20 ../
-r-------- 1 root root   1150 Aug 31 17:54 favicon.ico
drw------- 2 root root   4096 Jan 13 22:51 static/
-rw------- 1 root root 883381 Jan 23 20:09 tdm.log
-rwx------ 1 root root  73577 Jan 23 21:37 tdm.py*
-rw------- 1 root root  56445 Jan 23 21:37 tdm.pyc
drw------- 2 root root   4096 Jan 23 20:08 templates/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    493 Jan 23 22:42 wsgi.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    720 Jan 23 22:42 wsgi.pyc
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Jan 24 19:47 wsgi.sock=
```

**Supervisor Config File**

```
root@ilg40:~# cat /etc/supervisor/conf.d/wsgi_flask.conf 
[program:wsgi_flask]
command = gunicorn --preload --bind unix:/etc/tdm/flask/wsgi.sock --workers 4 --pythonpath /etc/tdm/flask wsgi 
process_name = wsgi_flask
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile = /var/log/wsgi_flask/wsgi_flask.out.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/wsgi_flask/wsgi_flask.err.log
```

**Update Supervisord About The New Process**

```
root@ilg40:~# supervisorctl update
wsgi_flask: added process group
```

**Checking Process Status**

```
root@ilg40:~# supervisorctl status wsgi_flask
wsgi_flask                       RUNNING    pid 1129, uptime 0:29:12
```

**Note:** in the setup above, I'm not using `virtualenv`, which I believe that could require the configuration of **directory** variable for the process and also, to configure environment PATH for the **command** variable (adding env PATH="$PATH:/the/app/path" gunicorn...), since that gunicorn, flask, and so on, are only located inside of the virtualenv.